# How to convert byte array to image in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image

I am trying to convert raw data of length 64372(w= 242, h=266) to the image, the raw data is in the format of the byte array, I want to convert this byte array into image, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a `bytearray` of dummy data representing a gradient like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate a left-right gradient 242 px wide by 266 pixels tall
ba = bytearray((np.arange(242) + np.zeros((266,1))).astype(np.uint8))
```

For reference, that array will contain data like this:

```
array([[  0.,   1.,   2., ..., 239., 240., 241.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2., ..., 239., 240., 241.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2., ..., 239., 240., 241.],
       ...,
       [  0.,   1.,   2., ..., 239., 240., 241.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2., ..., 239., 240., 241.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2., ..., 239., 240., 241.]])
```

And then make into a PIL/Pillow image like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Convert bytearray "ba" to PIL Image, 'L' just means greyscale/lightness
im = Image.frombuffer('L', (242,266), ba, 'raw', 'L', 0, 1)
```

Then you can save the image like this:

```
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Documentation is [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html).

Comment: Hi Mark, can you please help me on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299094/convert-from-bytearray-to-image-of-498-length

Comment: Hi Mark, how are you? I needed your help on this, can you please help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069334/how-to-convert-list-of-integers-to-image-using-pil-in-python3