# Conversion 2-dimensional rgb matrix to PNG Image with Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, image, matrix, png, data-conversion

I need to convert a 2-dimensional 24bit rgb- matrix with Python 3.6

```
[[rr11gg11bb11, rr12gg12bb12,..  ..,rr1mgg1mbb1m],
.
.
 [rri1gg11bb11, rr12ggi2bb12,..  ..,rr1mgg1mbb1m]
.
.
 [rrn1ggn1bbn1, rrn2ggn2bbn2,.. ..,rrmnggmnbbmn]]
```

into an image of the format tif, png and jpg.

I've also got the matrix in form of a file

```
image.bin.
```

From this binary file I can whatch the image with the help of a RAW Pixel Viewer:

```
http://rawpixels.net/
```

I have found the PIL library, but I didn't find any method to build an image object out of these data. How can I do that? I use Python 3.6.

Now I've tried the following:

```
im = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (self.width, self.height), self.matrix, 'raw', 
'RGB', 0, 1)              
logger.info("image object created.")
im.save('result.png')
logger.info("image saved as result.png")
```

But I get the message:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

Now I've found out that I must convert the object into a bytearray:

```
 npm = np.array(self.matrix)
 arr = bytearray(npm)
 print(arr)
 im = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (self.width, self.height), arr, 'raw', 
'RGB', 0, 1)
```

The conversion just works, when I use 'L', or 'RGBA', but not with 'RGB'. Strangely in this case it refuses a bytearray object.

Comment: Look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075903/2836621 You will need `'RGB'` rather than `'L'`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The `ba` seems to be my Matrix. So I've done the following:

Comment: Don't put code in comments area. Either add it to your question if it doesn't work, or add it as an answer if it does. Then accept it as correct and grab the points:-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok, I've done so. But it doesn't create the image. I thought I don't have to make the 1st step shown in Your link, because the matrix I've already got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

So, essentially, you don't have a Numpy array, but you have a list of lists wherein each element is a **single** 24-bit number that represents an RGB triplet RGB888.

So, I can make a representation of your list like this:

```
f=[ 
[0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0x000000,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF],
[0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0x000000,0x000000,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF],
[0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0x000000,0xFFFFFF,0x000000,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF],
[0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0x000000,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF],
[0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0x000000,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF]
]
```

So, I can make that into a Numpy array of uint32 elements like this:

```
na = np.array(f).astype(np.uint32)
```

And then make an RGB array that PIL will like using:

```
h,w = 5,10
RGB=np.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8)
```

Then I just have to shift and copy the triplets into the right places:

```
RGB[:,:,0] = na>>16            # Take red from top
RGB[:,:,1] = (na>>8) & 0xff    # Take green from middle
RGB[:,:,2] = na & 0xff         # Take blue from bottom
```

Now I can make a PIL image from that RGB array and save it to disk:

```
pIm = Image.fromarray(RGB).save('result.png')
```

**Original Answer**

Let's create a file of test data with **ImageMagick**. First as a PNG, just so you can see it:

```
magick -size 640x480 gradient:magenta-yellow image.png
```

[image]

And now the same thing again, but this time as RGB888 to match your file:

```
magick -size 640x480 gradient:magenta-yellow -depth 8 rgb:image.bin
```

---

Now:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the file and read contents into "data"
with open('image.bin','rb') as f: 
    data = f.read() 

# Convert that into PIL Image
im = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (640, 480), data, 'raw', 'RGB', 0, 1)

# Save
im.save('result.png')
```

---

You could equally let Numpy read the file and then convert the result to a PIL Image:

```
import numpy as np

im = Image.fromarray(np.fromfile('image.bin',dtype=np.uint8).reshape(480,640,3))
```

---

If you want to check your binary file actually contains what you think it contains, you can also convert it to a PNG with **ImageMagick** to test it. Say you think the file is 640 pixels wide by 480 pixels tall and RGB888, you can ask **ImageMagick** to make it into a PNG with:

```
magick -depth 8 -size 640x480 RGB:<YOURFILENAME> image.png
```

Or, if you think it is a single 16-bit, single channel greyscale image with a 128 byte header that you want to ignore:

```
magick -depth 16 -size 640x480+128 GRAY:<YOURFILENAME> image.png
```

**Keywords**: Raw, raw image, binary file, image, image processing, Python, ImageMagick, convert.

Comment: Note that you don't need the first step again - I just create dummy data because there is none supplied n the question.

Comment: Thanks, the Magick file conversion works, wherelse the array to png file conversion still makes trouble.

Comment: Ok, the problem is either that you are reading your file the wrong way, or that your file is not how you think. So please share your file :-) If you don't want to post it on a public site, you are welcome to Email mark@thesetchells.com Please also say the image height and width and which is which. ie N pixels wide and M pixels tall.

Comment: No no.. the suggestion You have posted about converting a bin file to a png works perfectly. Even without the first code line that uses magick. But now I was asked to convert the 2-dimensional 24-bit Matrix directly to tif, png, jpeg format. It's only this what makes me trouble - as described in the lower part of my question. Could You pls help me another time? Thanks.

Comment: @Uwe_98 You haven't provided an image. You only described your image so I made one matching your description and the code reads it. So the code is correct. The only possibility is that your image is not as described, so until you provide an image, I can't do anything else. Please provide your image.

Comment: Your image gradient magneta Yellow is perfect. As I wrote, the 2 step conversion - first from 2-dimensional RGB888 to binfile and then from binfile to pngfile works. But what I need now is the direct conversion from the matrix of the picture that You have posted to the png-file in the same way as You have demonstrated in the example of the grey scale gradient (the link that You have suggested. I have tried it out but it doesn't accept RGB as data type, only RGBA and L.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please ensure your question provides an image, or a couple of lines to generate a dummy image and a description of what you want to get from it. Until you provide a **Minimum Complete Verifiable Example**  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I cannot help you further - it just wastes everybody's time guessing what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: I've sent You a mail.

Comment: Yes, it's like this, where white (0xFFFFFF) is Always the backgroundcolor and just black (0x000000) can be replaced by red (0xFF0000), green (0x00FF00), or blue (0x0000FF).